# Binding Items to silverlight combobox in MVVM Architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

i am creating one property in entity class like below

```
public class Myclass
{
private string _Selecteditem;
public string SelectedItem
{
get{return _Selecteditem;}
set{_Seleteditem = value;
}
}
```

in xaml page i am binding Combobox like below

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbCountry" Grid.Column="14" Grid.Row="0" Width="150" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry,Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="--Select--" Content="--Select--"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="US" Content="US" />
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="CA" Content="CA" />
                <ComboBox.SelectedIndex>0</ComboBox.SelectedIndex>
            </ComboBox>
```

i want add this selected item to querystring in Model class, i am trying like below

```
Myclass myclass = new MyClass();     
QueryString.Add("SeletedItem", Convert.ToString(myclass.SelectedItem.Value));
```

here i am getting SelectedItem value as System.Web.ComboItem, but i want if i select 'US' as dropdown i need to get 'US'. how to get the value please can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring combobox items in the xaml code, declare a them as an `ObservableCollection` in the model. Then bind this property to `Items` property of the combobox in the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `QueryString.Add("SeletedItem",(myclass.SelectedItem.Value as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString());`